# Creating a search box in SharePoint that will search an external database

Tags: search, sql

Is there a way to create a search box in SharePoint that searches an external SQL database that is connected to SharePoint?

Comment: How is the SQL database connected to SharePoint?

Comment: I'm using the connection string wizard through sharePoint designer.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using Business Connectivity Services. This will allow you to connect to the SQL database, view items in SharePoint, as well as search for them, within the existing SP setup.

If you want to keep it outside of BCS, you'll need to create the search experience custom, from the search box to the search results page.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an External Content Type to the external data. Ensure that
   you meet the requirements for indexing the content.
2. Create a Content Source for the BCS data in the Search Service Application
3. Create a Result Type (2013) or Scope (2010) and limit the results to your Content Source
4. Create a Results page that limits the results to your Result Source (or Scope)
5. Wire up your search box so it sends it's input to your Search Results Page

Done, all out of the box.